# Problems trying to deploy on azure a sample web application

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I am trying to deploy an Hello World sample web application on Windows Azure, but I'm running into problems for which I can't find the answer.

First, I can't create a new Hosted Service to deploy it because the "new hosted service window" is bugged as you can see below, the "Choose a subscription" and "Choose a region" dialog are just empty, so I can't upload my package to deploy it.

[image: New hosted service window]

Then when I go to the "Hosted Service" screen, my 3-month trial is marked as disabled :

[image: main hosted service window]

And if I try to publish via Visual Studio, I can't import my credentials downloaded from the link in the dialog, as shows the picture below :

[image: Visual studio error]

If anybody knows how to fix it, I'm would love to hear !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your 3 months trial is disabled, you won't be able to create a hosted service and you won't be able to deploy from Visual Studio. It seems that you've signed up for the trial on 12/22, I would contact support and figure out why your 3 months trial is disabled.